# How to Run Cucumber 6 CLI

Tags: java, cucumber, command-line-interface

I had coded in cucumber 6 and tried to run in intellij.
This code will be run in CI/CD environment as well.

How to run cucumber 6 in CLI?

I tried with the following code but resulted error.

```
java cucumber.api.cli.Main
```

Please see error below.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main
```

JUnit 4 Runner

```
java -cp target/ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.cimb.TestManager.ParallelRunner
```

Error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: `java -cp <path to cucumber jar folder> io.cucumber.core.cli.Main -g <glue_path> <feature_path>`

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.